# Unexpected exception parsing XML document NoClassDefFoundError XMLSchemaValidator

Tags: java, spring, junit, java-11

I'm getting below error while running junit test cases. Usually such `NoClassDefFoundError` should occur due to version conflict but I don't see any issue with that here.

**Error**

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [test-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator
```

**Spring dependency**

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep spring
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-redis-spring-data2:jar:0.1.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:test
```

```xml
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-javaagent:jar:1.7.1:test
```

**Maven compiler plugin**

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Maven and Java version**

````
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home```
````

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator

Comment: that's right. This is the class. I see that it comes from rt.jar

Comment: <dependency>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Have you validated the XML structure? verify through any formatter ..might help

Comment: If I set the java_home to java 8, it works. Therefore it doesn't look like xml structure issue unless schema is not compatible (but changing that also didn't help)

Comment: @K.Nicholas adding this dependency fixes the issue. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Lucky guess I suppose.